# Remove some HTML tags from a string if it is a duplicate from the previous tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string like this:

```
The user have to press the button </br> </br> </br> Then find the 
right folder </br> </br> </br> Those the correct name.
```

The problem is all the spaces. I want to just have one space. Somehow I have to check for duplicates but I don't know how?

I have tried to replace all the html tags but then none of the tags are shown:

```
htmlstring.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ' ');
```

I have also tried to just replace the br tags:

```
htmlstring.replace(/<[//]{0,1}(B|b)[^><]*>/g,"");
```

I want the string to look like this:

```
The user have to press the button </br> Then find the 
right folder </br> Those the correct name.
```

Comment: you should read [this famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Your br tags have the slash in the wrong place (also the slash is no longer needed in html5 and was only used in html4 if your doc was set to xhtml)

Comment: also, you're using the wrong slash to escape the slash (should be `\/` not `//`). also instead of {0,1} all you need is a `?`, which makes the preceding element optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
htmlstring.replace(/((<\/br>\s?){2,})/g, '$2')
```

1. it finds only the substrings, which contain multiple line-breaks - **{2,}**
2. it replaces to only one - reference to the result of the second group
3. it does it repeatedly in the whole string - **g** flag

P.s. I often use [regexpal](https://www.regexpal.com/) to test my regexes, this is a really informative and fast way to write it.

Answer (score 0):

For this simple example you could use:

```
htmlstring.replace(/((<[^>]*>)\s*){1,}/g, '$1')
```